# How to Stop Closing Command Prompt

Tags: java

Suppose If we create a bat file to run java program which prints `"Hello World"` , like this

`javac MyProgram.java
java MyProgram`

After when I Double click that bat file It opens Command prompt and displays `"Hello World"` result and automatically closes. Is there any solution to  not to close Command prompt until and unless I type Exit in it.

Thanks.

Comment: That is a totally beginner Java question. Did you work on a tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the window remain for a while, there are 3 ways:

- Run that command `javac MyProgram.java java MyProgram` in a `Command Prompt`window (fire up a new one, navigate to your working directory, execute it)
- Get a char (`Scanner a; ... ; a.nextLine()`) at the end of your program, you can then enter something or simply press a  to make the program complete.
- Make the current thread sleep for some time so that you can see the output. Try: `try { Thread.Sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) {}`

Comment: @JayaSantosh if i helped you, accept the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because at the end of the day it is a program. And it terminates once it is done with its execution..in your case, printing stuff.

You can manually open a command prompt and then drag and drop the .bat file onto this command prompt and run it. This way, you would still have the window open.